# How to import Android samples into an Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse

android-sdk-windows\samples contains various samples. Is there a mechanism to eclipsify all samples as android eclipse projects, so that it can be viewed in an Eclipse environment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `File` -> `New` -> `Android Project` and select 'Create project from existing source' to import an existing project. However, sometimes it's headbangingly annoying to get it to work right.

In the New Android Project dialogue there's also a radio button option 'Create project from existing sample', which, coming to think of it, is probably what you want to use in this case.

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you referring to? Indigo does not have the option "Create project from existing sources" Please confirm...

Comment: @gath, I don't recall what version of Eclipse I was using at the time, but I am now using Indigo, and it **does** have this option still. They've just changed the menu structure a bit. You now use File -> New -> Project -> Android Project and then select the "Create project from existing source" radio button.

Comment: It seems hit or miss in eclipse 4.2. The menus are slightly different. I think this lives under File->New->Project...->Android Project from Existing Code, but it still didn't work for me. I was trying to import the project in the zip file at http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Answer (score 15):

To import a sample project go to:
File >> New >> Other >> Android >> Android Sample Project

When you use the Android SDK Manager to install the samples, Eclipse will recognize the path and will provide you with a list of Sample Projects installed in your computer.

Comment: this should be the answer. flawless.

Answer (score 3):

File->New -> Others->Android->Android sample project ->Select api level ->select sample project ->open

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse Juno you can go to File - New Project - Android - Android Sample Project. You need to select a build target and then just select from a bunch of sample projects which you should have downloaded using Eclipse-Help- Install Software etc. All the sample projects show up with the Droid icon. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming eclipse is setup with the Android ADT, you should be able to add a new Android project and point it to the existing folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do them all at once - you have to do them one at a time.  The answer from @Trev16v provides the steps; repeat for each sample of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in ADT.

File --> New --> Project.. --> Android Sample Project(Inside Android) --> (Select your build target) and finish.
If you installed the sample projects, it will show the list of projects. Select and open.