# Android-NDK: create GUI elements out of native code

Tags: android, user-interface, opengl-es, android-ndk, java-native-interface

as far as I understood the Android-NDK-thingy it works as follows: I have to use a NativeActivity that itself calls into the attached native code handing over some OpenGL graphics context. This context can be used by the native part to draw some things with.

What I could not fiddle out until now: how about some GUI elements? Is there a possibility to call back from native code to Java just to create some UI-elements and perhaps to use layouts? Means is it possible to use the standard Android GUI elements also with such native code?

If yes: how can this be done? If not: what alternatives exist (except drawing everything manually)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use GUI stuff on the openGL view, I think it would be better to use a normal Activity instead of a NativeActivity.
You can use the Android sample called GL2JNIActivity. Check [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307399/how-to-import-android-samples-into-an-eclipse-ide) to import it from Eclipse.

You can declare some native functions in the JNI Library part (class JNILib in the sample). which you will call when you your GUI listeners get called. Basically it will look like that:

```
public class GL2JNILib {

 static {
     // Maybe you need to load other relevant libraries here
     System.loadLibrary("gl2jni");
 }

 public static native void init(int width, int height);
 public static native void step();

 /*Add here your native functions to send to the native code*/     
 public static native void buttonClicked();
 //... add other listeners here (i.e: screen touched, etc.)
```

}

Then in the Activity itself (in the sample that corresponds to the class JNIActivity), you can just load an XML GUI file as usual. When you get some input through the GUI, you can just call the native functions added in the GL2JNI class. More or less it will look like that:

```
public class GL2JNIActivity extends Activity {

    GL2JNIView mView;
    Button mButton;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        mView = new GL2JNIView(getApplication());
        setContentView(mView);
        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.your_button);        
        mButton.setOnClickListener( new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mView.buttonClicked();
            }
        });
    }

    /*...*/
}
```

Finally, you have to implement the native function in the native side:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_buttonClicked(
            JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    // will be called when the button is clicked
}
```